# Unable to inject mock in Spring java bean?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have a spring boot test as below

```
@SpringBootTest(class=AppConfig.class)
Public class AppTest{

   @Autowired
    private Product product

    @Test
     Public void test(){
      .....
      .....
     }
}
```

My AppConfig.class is as below

```
 Public clas AppConfig{

    @Mock
    EMailService emailService;

    public AppConfig(){
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }


      @Bean
       Public Product getProduct(){
                return new Product();
         }
    }

Class Product{
@Autowired
private EMailService emailService
.....
......
}
```

Even after i defined @Mock EMailService emailService, whem i run the test, I get error EMailService bean not defined.

Comment: Shouldn't `EMailService` instead be `EmailService`? Just a little typo, it seems.

Comment: Thanks. But that was a typo. I corrected it.

Comment: Don't you mean `@MockBean` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your AppTest class

```
@SpringBootTest(class=AppConfig.class)
public class AppTest{

 @Mock
 private EMailService emailService;  

 @InjectMocks
 private Product product;

 @Test
 public void test(){
  .....
  .....
 }
}
```

Also, I think you do not need the definitions in the AppConfig class anymore